# How to remove the box frame in “levelplot” in R package “rasterVis”

Tags: r, raster, lattice, figure, rastervis

I want to remove the box frame in my "levelplot" figure for raster data sets. Don't know how to do it.

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)

f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r <- raster(f)
s <- stack(r, r+500, r-500)
levelplot(s, contour=TRUE)
levelplot(s)
levelplot(s,box=FALSE,axes=FALSE) # It doesn't work.
```

Answer (score 12):

**[Edit: Figures added]**

What you want to achieve is described in the last example of `?wireframe`

```
levelplot(s, contour = TRUE, par.settings = list(axis.line = list(col = "transparent")), 
          scales = list(col = "black"))`
```

[image: Box frame removed]

If you want to remove strip background and color:

```
levelplot(s, contour=TRUE, par.settings = list(axis.line = list(col = "transparent"), 
          strip.background = list(col = 'transparent'), 
          strip.border = list(col = 'transparent')), 
          scales = list(col = "black"))`
```

[image: Box frame, strip background and color removed]

Comment: hi this is really useful but for me the axis ticks are being removed, using the exact code you have used, any idea why? thanks